# Доступ к объекту из другого файла с исходным кодом

Tags: c++, классы

Создаю экземпляр класса в функции main, как мне получить доступ к этому экземпляру из метода другого класса который находится в другом файле исходного кода и включается в функцию main (впоследствии чего в той же функции main и используется)?

Answer (score 3):

Передать его методу этого класса в качестве параметра.

```
class Other
{
    void method(const FromMain& m);
    ...

int main()
{
    FromMain a;
    Other b;
    ...
    b.method(a);
```

Это вас интересует? Если нет - уточните свой вопрос, потому как без точного ТЗ результат ХЗ...

**Update**
Можно - если известно, что время жизни объекта `FromMain` превышает время жизни `Other` - хранить ссылку прямо в `Other`:

```
class Other
{
    Other(FromMain& M):m(M) {...}
    void method() { ... Работа с m ... }
    ...
    FromMain& m;



int main()
{
    FromMain a;
    Other b(a);
    ...
    b.method();
```

Comment: Да, интересный способ, он подходит но только не совсем, т.к. у меня на самом деле большое количество методов что должны иметь доступ к этому объекту и всем им передавать ссылку на объект подобным образом слегка затруднительно. Я не так давно занимаюсь C++, может быть есть какой нибудь более простой способ который я упускаю?

Comment: Ну, раз вам нужно обращаться к нему в любом случае - то все равно в теле метода вы будете вынуждены его указать... Ну, гляньте второй вариант - сейчас в ответе допишу.

Comment: @nammidd В таком случае, вероятно, Вам подойдёт глобальная статическая переменная.